# org.springframework.core.convert Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have spring app (JPA/Hibernate + PostgeSQL). I have Label and LabelRepository classes.

**Label**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "label", schema = "public")
public class Label implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "label_id", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "order")
    private Integer order;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String groupName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "label")
    private List<VehicleLabel> vehicleLabels = new ArrayList<>(0);
}
```

**LabelRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface LabelRepository extends BaseJpaRepository<Label, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select l.* from vehicle_label vl left join label l on l.label_id = vl.label_id where vl.vehicle_label_id = :vehicle_label_id", nativeQuery = true)
    public Label getLabelFromVehicleLabel(@Param("vehicle_label_id") Integer vehicleLabelId);
}
```

It is giving me result like this:

```
label_id|code   |name   |description|order|status|type|group_name|
--------+-------+-------+-----------+-----+------+----+----------+
      24|suv_cuv|SUV/CUV|           |     |active|C   |SUV       |
```

And i have error:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.bave.service.database.entity.Label] for value '{24, suv_cuv, SUV/CUV, null, null, active, C, SUV}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [com.bave.service.database.entity.Label]

it seems it can't map with entity class

Thanks!

Comment: Why a SQL and not a JPQL? Something like `SELECT l FROM Label l WHERE l. vehicleLabels.vehicle_label_id = :vehicle_label_id`, That way you use entities and hibernate should be able to do the mapping. Also your method probably returns more then 1 label so your return type should probably be `List<Label>` instead of `Label`.